# Why a fork is often followed by an exec?

Tags: unix, process

Why "a fork is often followed by an exec"?
Can't you just create a new process in UNIX?

Comment: I am citing Rago from his APUE book.

Comment: On U&L SE: [Why is the default process creation mechanism fork?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31118/108618) [Why do we need to fork to create new processes?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/136637/108618)

Comment: Because exec's don't like to eat with their hands?

Comment: Actually I believe that in Linux the real core function to spawn new processes is [`clone`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html), which is used both to create new processes and new threads. You can specify various flags to `clone` to tell it to copy/share certain kinds of memory/file descriptors etc, so you can end up either creating a whole new process same as a plain fork, or a new thread that shares the same memory space.

Comment: Other time-sharing OSes contemporary to Unix development (e.g., VMS, TSO) had spawn() system calls that needed many options and thus were extremely complex. Splitting spawn into fork() and exex() replaced that complexity with two relatively simple calls with some program code between them.

Comment: exec will replace the current process (or not if they fail), fork will create a clone of the current process

Comment: Why is it that, when you find a left shoe, there’s usually a right shoe nearby?  Why are beaches so often close to bodies of water? … … … … … … … … … … What is it that you really want to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A slightly different perspective from most of the "fork-shaming" existing answers... ;)

Originally it was probably, as @davidbak mentioned, just so temptingly easy to do it this way. But having worked with `fork`/`exec` a lot (and also often with only `fork`, for multiprocessing) there definitely are reasons why this way of working is still alive and kicking, and not delegated to the fog of history:

- It still is extremely simple from the view of a programmer in literally any programming language at all. It does not matter where I am coding - any language can trust the extremely simple implications of the `fork` semantics and offer it as part of the language. Hence, every language has a relatively trivial (compared to in-process multithreading) method of offering at least multi-processing to its users. (N.B.: one exception to this is if you are using multithreading in your program - [after a fork, only one thread is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6056903/multithreaded-fork); this can lead to obvious issues in all but the most trivial multithreading applications.)
- As a user (programmer), I can write my multiprocessing in a few lines of code, with no worry about mutexes, semaphores, illegally overwriting state of any of my program variables, and so on and so forth. At the same time, the "initial communication" between parent child is also trivially handled for me - the child does have full access to any variables or RAM the parent had, and can continue working with it.
  In practice this means, if I, say, have a need to perform some short I/O or networking process in parallel to my main program, I can do that with a few lines of code; all is in one place, easily visible. I can collect the child afterwards and be on my merry way. There are no "worker threads", I do not need to take care to use only thread-safe methods or data structures.
- Again, since the memory content starts identical but is in effect separate, there is zero risk of overwriting anything between parent/child processes. Yes, I do have to find other ways to to IPC then between parent and child, but those methods are not *that* hard either; often, languages offer a standard function like "open3" or something like that which automatically provides bi-directional pipe-based file handles for communication to avoid deadlocks and such.
- Specifically, when switching between programming languages, once one has understood the `fork` semantics, one never needs to learn anything more about the new environment - it's always as simple as in any other language.
- It is nice to have `exec` anyways. It allows us to replace the current process image (i.e. the executable that's being executed) with something different. This makes it clean to, say, have some script or program that prepares some kind of environment and then execs something else, while disappearing from the scene, itself. Not only does it free resources (RAM, but also space in the process table, and so on), but makes it very clear to anybody involved or looking at it that the erstwhile parent is not going to play any role whatsoever anymore in the future. You often find this in well-written `bash` scripts, which free up the resources of the `bash` interpreter when starting their "payload".

In addition:

- It perfectly fits the Unix philosophy of having many small tools which can interact with each other, instead of fat black boxes that are either very limited, or need a big set of parameters or an API to really use.
- As shown above, it is powerful in some scenarios where only having a single function would be limiting; but it is also still easy enough to have `fork`+`exec` following each other. It's not like you *have* to do a lot of stuff inbetween (or any at all, really) unless you need it.
- As per the man pages, in some modern Unixes (namely, Linux), [fork](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) itself [is only a wrapper around](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html#NOTES) the more modern and more powerful [clone](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) call, which indeed is somewhat like a `fork+exec`. Note that here we see complexity raise its ugly head already; Linux also has a [clone3](https://man.archlinux.org/man/clone3.2.en) function which supersedes `clone` and makes the interface a little easier or more convenient (using `structs` instead of so many flags).

Comment: _“Any language can trust the extremely simple implications of the `fork` semantics and offer it as part of the language”_ - *Any* language…? Then where is it in Java? C#? Erlang? Ada? BASIC? Cobol? Haskell?

Comment: @Dai All of them can call it through their native call systems, and it will break none of their runtimes if you where to do so.

Comment: @user1937198 a very bold statement indeed

Comment: @Dai, yes, those languages could offer fork-based multiprocessing, if they wanted. Emphasis on "can". I'm sure for all of those the reason they don't isn't technical problems but a design decision (possibly to stay platform-independent).

Comment: @user1937198 this isn't true. It will break at least. Net. Probably Java too.

Comment: @JeromeHaltom How? There are issues with regards to I/O on parallel threads, but thats not a runtime issue. The only issue I can see is that the background threads for things like GC. And even that isn't necessarily a problem if you only use a small amount of memory before running an exec.

Comment: @user1937198 Because the generated machine code may have a safe point, that is, a call into the GC. And you cannot control where these are. If the GC marks the world as needing a global pause, then fork() happens, and a safe point exists after the fork() but before the exec(), then the thread will pause. Without any actually running GC to unpause it ever. This is why System.Diagnostics.Process on Unix is implemented in C.

Comment: Thanks @JeromeHaltom for this example; I have added it to the answer.

Answer (score 43):

`fork()` creates a new process, which is a **copy** of the parent process. So if you did only `fork()`, you would have two identical processes running. Therefore in order to replace the forked process with another code, you need to perform `exec()` which replaces the currently running process with the specified executable file.

Linux kernel is just organized that way. You don't have a single system call that creates new process and loads a new executable at the same time. You have to do it in two steps - first create new process, then load a new executable into this new process. (Although you may have a **library function** in your programming language that combines these two - for example there is `spawn()` in many C variants).

Sometimes `exec()` is not needed, if just creating another copy of the current process is all that you want. Many daemons for example do this.

Comment: The answer is not really Linux-specific. I think BSDs do the same.

Comment: @fraxinus I'm pretty sure this comes from original UNIX systems, so this has been the same for like 50+ years now.

Comment: `Linux kernel is just organized that way` that's absolutely not true. It's the Unix way. Linux has many other ways to spawn new processes

Comment: A single multiprocessing programme could `fork()` several times, then distribute calculations based on the process ID?

Comment: @gerrit Probably yes. I'm not too much into numerical programming; but for example network daemons like web servers or SSH servers do it all the time. They have a single master process that forks when a network request is coming, and the forked process serves that request, then if there are no more requests exits after some time.

Comment: Yes, @gerrit, but it would be more typical to use multiple threads in one process than multiple processes.  Especially if they want to share memory.

Comment: @JohnBollinger why is it more typical to use threads?

Comment: @fabiomaia, because you don't need any special setup for threads of the same process to share memory with each other.  They do this automatically -- that's one of the main characteristics distinguishing threads from separate processes.

Answer (score 33):

This is because of historical reasons:  At the beginning of time there was only `fork` and `exec`.  Because it was *easy to implement* (according to DMR: only 27 lines of PDP-7 assembly code for `fork`! - see e.g. [*A `fork()` in the road* (Baumann, Appavoo, Krieger, Roscoe, 2019)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/uploads/prod/2019/04/fork-hotos19.pdf) - a secondary source, though it references a primary source *The Evolution of the Unix time-sharing system* (Ritchie, 1979).  Anyway, true *ab initio* direct process creation came much much much much later.  (And is not in POSIX, possibly?)

The fact that a true direct process creation API came much much later affects Unix programming to this day.  Because hundreds of books, manuals, tutorials, slide decks, and courses were written explaining `fork` and `exec` and they've been taught to students and programmers for decades as *the* way to do process creation/control in Unix and that *extensive* heritage persists in the way code is written *to this day*.

---

Oh, here is [*The Evolution of the Unix Time-sharing System* (Ritchie, 1979)](https://read.seas.harvard.edu/%7Ekohler/class/aosref/ritchie84evolution.pdf). Scroll down to page 6 to see: "Process control in its modern form was designed and implemented within a couple of days. ..... In fact, the PDP-7's *fork* call required precisely 27 lines of assembly code."

Comment: Nice bit of history - thanks for doing the research.  Scary to think how much of this stuff has happened during my lifetime!

Comment: Does anyone know what the *ab initio* direct process creation API is called in Unix?  I'd like to read about it, if it exists.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner isn't it called "boot"? The kernel starts the first process (e.g. /bin/init). Init starts everything else by fork and exec.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner `posix_spawn`. On many POSIX implementations, it's a library function on top of `fork` and `exec`, since those have to exist anyway and can't be implemented on top of `posix_spawn`.

Comment: It should be noted that `posix_spawn()` is not intended or positioned as somehow more fundamental than `fork()`, as can be seen by the fact that the former can be implemented on top of the latter, but not *vice versa*.  The primary goal of `posix_spawn()` is to provide for process creation on systems with capabilities too limited to support `fork()`, such as those without MMUs.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - but as that paper I linked "A fork() in the road" points out - if you _do_ implement it natively (as has been done) it performs excellently - much better than fork/exec in many common cases.  (Due to not needing copy-on-write, mostly.)

Answer (score 13):

Because an exec doesn't create a process, and linux doesn't have a single syscall for create process and load executable because that only works in the trivial case of creating a process with new executable with no preexisting resources. If you want to do anything more than the trivial case, the complexity rapidly ramps up, and it becomes easier to have separate 'create process' and 'start executable' steps with the ability to manipulate the process in between. See https://lwn.net/Articles/360556/ for a discussion on this.

Unix, going back to the earliest versions has solved this by using fork to create a duplicate of the parent process dedicated to setting up the environment, which then loads in the new executable, once it has completed. The child process then exists in a temporary state of having access to all the resources of the parent process, but of running in the child process. This approach has a couple of advantages:

1. You can use the existing in-process manipulation APIs to set up the child process. This means you don't then need a whole family of API calls for manipulating the child process to set up resources.
2. You can use exec on its own if the parent process will no longer need to exist after creating the new one.
3. You can fork without using exec if you want a second process of the same executable.

Comment: See also: clone() and posix_spawn()

Comment: This is more like a rationalization than a proper reason.  IMO.  _Other_ systems besides Unix have been able to create processes from scratch.

Comment: It's more than a rationalization, it's a design philosophy. Unics [sic] simplicity was inspired as a counter to Multics complexity, so if `fork` was a good way to duplicate a process when you wanted a duplicate, and `exec` was a good way to replace the executable image when you wanted to replace it, why waste time and resources implementing another way to do the same thing? https://multicians.org/unix.html

Comment: @BowlOfRed posix_spawn is not a linux syscall. It is emulated. Clone is basically fork with the ability to handle some extremely common configuration cases more efficiently, along with better safety from multi-threading. It does not have the ability to do fork + exec in a single step.

Comment: @davidbak Sometimes a good rationalization is acceptable as a reason, especially in this case when the alternative is the monstrosity that is the Windows [CreateProcess](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) function...

Comment: @kbro It may have been good when unics was created, but it's not good now. Justifying it now is absolutely a rationalization. A good process creation API nowadays would be something like creating an empty shell of a process, then loading memory and creating stopped threads in the process, then starting it.

Comment: @user253751 I don't see anybody saying "this is the ideal way that it would be designed in any OS and should never be changed", they are saying "this was the sound reasoning that led to this decision back then". Saying "well, here's a third way it could work which I think is better" in no way invalidates the fact that the design chosen had clear advantages over how other OSes implemented it.

Comment: @user253751 So there are complications to that, specifically that you then need an API surface for manipulating that empty shell of a process without being in it. You end up needing a whole family of syscalls designed for manipulating that empty shell from outside. With the fork/clone + exec, you can use the standard process manipulation syscalls, because the setup code runs inside the process, but with access to the parents resources.

Comment: @user1937198 yes, but some of the clone flags amount to "save some work and don't bother duplicating things because this child will never do anything but exec", and posix_spawn can of course make use of that :)

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn Interestingly, under the hood, NtCreateProcess is even more bare bones than fork() and does absolutely nothing with creating an executable thread, or mapping an image into the space.  Too much of Windows' complexity and non-orthogonality is from backward compatibility.  :/

Comment: @user253751 OP asked about UNIX, which was developed 50 years ago, so going off on a tangent about how you might design something with a clean sheet of paper starting today is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot create a new process in UNIX, you can only duplicate your current process (using `fork`). If you want the new process to do something other than exactly what the current process is doing, you then replace it (using `exec`).

You do not have to `fork` before calling `exec`.  There's a common usage in scripts that start up a login session (`.xinitrc` and the like) where you set up environment variables and start background tasks (such as `ssh-agent`) and then run the session manager. There's nothing more for the startup script to do after launching the session manager so you `exec` it to free up the resources assigned to running your startup script. The parent of the startup script is unaware of this replacement - the PID remains the same - so they continue to wait for this child to die before they perform their tidy-up actions.